# AuthenticationSuccessHandler example for Spring Security 3

Tags: java, spring

I am a newbie to Spring Security 3 . I am using roles for users to login.

I want to redirect a user to a different page based on the role of that user, I understand is that I would have to implement the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` for the same, but some examples in that direction would help.

Thanks in advance,
Vivek

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public class Test implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_USER") {
            response.sendRedirect("/userpage");
        }
    }
}
```

In the XML config add this:

```xml
<bean id="authenticationFilter" class="YOUR_AUTH_FILTER_HERE">
    <!-- There might be more properties here, depending on your auth filter!! -->
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler" />
</bean> 

<bean id="successHandler" class="Test"/>
```

Comment: ok , and in the spring-security.xml , how can i include this custom handler ( Test )

Comment: Coolest way which I could ever get to solve my problem. Thanks a lot. I searched for whole day and finally got this post. Thank you very much, you solved my problem too !!!