# How to make redirect go to different pages after login?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

In my project I have problem with redirect. After successful login (from all pages), I have redirect to previous page, but for one login page I should do redirect to main page(if i don't do this, I have redirect from login page back to login page).

This my `spring-security.xml`

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-page="/spring/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginFail"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"/>
    <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
    <remember-me key="remKey" user-service-ref="UserDetailsServiceImpl"
        token-validity-seconds="2419200" />
</http>
<!-- After login, return to the last visited page -->
<beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:property name="useReferer" value="true" />
</beans:bean>
```

EDIT:

I know that is a bad solution if I add this code in my login.jsp

```
<security:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
    <c:redirect url="/"/>
</security:authorize>
```

When user is authenticated, page auto redirects to my main page

Comment: You'll need to customize the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` to handle the special case.

Answer (score 1):

Utilise the AuthenticationSuccessHandler for manage where your landing is.

Please refer to these q & a for examples and further information:

[AuthenticationSuccessHandler example for Spring Security 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470405/authenticationsuccesshandler-example-for-spring-security-3)

http://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#form-login-flow-handling

Your other option is to capture redirects on that specific controller and further redirect it to the page you want:

e.g. HelloWorld -> Login -> HelloWorld Redirect -> HomePage