# Spring 4 MVC + Security login page redisplayed

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am implementing the security for my web application. The below are different event that takes place in authentication.

1) Successful login takes the users to the "dasboard" page.

2) Failure will take to the login page with the error.

3) The unauthenticated user access the secured page directly, redirected to the login, success takes to the dashboard, failure to the login with error.

4) The unauthenticated user access the secured page directly, redirected to the login, success takes to the dashboard, failure to the login with error.

### The problem,

1) The user is successfully authenticated, views the dashboard page. Again he navigates directly to the login page, login is displayed. But, why should it? Should it not, by default, redirect to the dashboard? Should I need to check in my login controller if the user has already logged-in and redirect to dashboard or any configuration I am missing?

2) I have 3 role of users, super admin, admin and user. Can I redirect to different pages based on different role of users? If so how? If not how can this be implemented?

3) Based on the configuration I should be able to switch between LDAP auth or DB. If the app needs to be authenticated, in future, with ldap shall I inject the auth provider based on configuration? How do configure multiple authenticators?

Please share your wisdom/docs/links on "this is how it should be done" spring-security

My WebSecurityConfig.java

```
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard").failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll().and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll();
    }
   @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
        AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) As you said this can be easily done in your login controller. Just send a redirect instead of the login page if you know that the user is already logged in.

2) I think you mean the redirect after the user logged in, are you?
This can be achieved using a custom [AuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html). Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470405/authenticationsuccesshandler-example-for-spring-security-3) can give you more details.

3) You can configure multiple [AuthenticationProviders](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html) (e.g. one for LDAP and one for DB) using an [ProviderManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.html) `AuthenticationManager`. An option would be to configure the `AuthenticationProviders` during startup in your java config based on the given environment or configuration values.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create session when the user login.and always check that login session on you login page...if session is caught ,redirect to dashboard,....if session in null let it live on login page...

2) Create sessions according to the which user is login, for example if "super user" logins, create session of "superUser"....and vice-versa...

Now check that session,if session has value of superUser,redirect it to desired page for super user....and vice versa...

In both of these using session is good choice.